# cannot call method replace on undefined script issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, undefined, typeof

What I am trying to do below since I don't have access to the PHP to my site, I am using this code to work around it. It will search for any links containing the two listed below. one from youtube with the /watch? in it and the other from youtube with just the /v in the url. It also is searching the any embedded elements. Problem is when I run the script it breaks all the other codes because of the error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Which is a pain in the butt! So I took it over to FF, says variable WT is not defined clearly it is though. Well it may not be since I used it outside the scope of the if statement. I'm not sure how to ensure if the link exist run the code. As well as if the Embed exist run the code too. These will be in my users post and want them automatically changed to work with my fancybox.

[Here is a live example](http://jsbin.com/agasux/1/edit)

Its the copied markup from my page with a quick linked CSS so don't mind the buggy look.

```
$(function() {
    //if link contains /watch?
    var t = $('.entry-content div div a[href*="youtube.com/watch?"]').attr('href');
    if(typeof t !== "undefined") {
        //do nothing don't run the script below
    } else {
        var d = $('.entry-content div div a[href*="youtube.com/watch?"]');
        var newsrc = t.replace('watch?','');
        var asrc = newsrc.replace('=','/');
        var g = asrc.replace('http://www.','http://img.');
        var s = g.replace('v','vi');
        d.attr('class','ez_video');
        d.attr('href', asrc).html('<img src="'+ s +'/0.jpg"/>');
    }
    //if link contains /v
    var wt = $('.entry-content div div a[href*="youtube.com/v"]').attr('href');

    if(typeof wt !== "undefined") {
        //do nothing don't run script below
    } else {
        var wd = $('.entry-content div div a[href*="youtube.com/v"]');
        var o = wt.replace('http://www.','http://img.');
        var v = o.replace('v','vi');
        wd.attr('class','ez_video');
        wd.attr('href', v).html('<img src="'+ v +'/0.jpg"/>');
    }

    //if embeded file
    var src = $('.entry-content').find('embed').attr('src');
    if (typeof src !== "undefined") {
        //do nothing again unless true run script below
    } else {
        var qload = src.replace('http://youtube.com/v/','');
        var y = src.replace('http://','http://img.');
        var imgsrc = y.replace('v','vi');
        $('embed').before('<a class="ez_video" id="'
            + qload +'" href="'+ src +'"><img src="'
            + imgsrc +'/0.jpg" tile="" alt=""/></a>');
        $('embed').remove();

    } 
    //Now make all work with the fancybox

    $('.ez_video').fancybox({
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'width'         : 854,
        'height'        : 480,
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
            'wmode'             : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is only running when your variables __are__ undefined. Why?

Comment: Wait really? I just kind of learned the typeof var !== "undefined" area does that mean if it is not undefined?

Comment: `!==` means "not equal"; `===` means "precisely equal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing it to a string of undefined while you should compare it the actual reserved word:

```
if(typeof wt !== undefined)
```

You can also do:

```
if(wt !== "undefined")
```

BTW, what you are doing is, if it is not undefined - do nothing, else - do something, is this really what you want?

Comment: typeof does in fact return a string, so testing against a string is absolutely correct... Please test answers in a console first.

Comment: Well I never used this type before. So basically what you are saying is that I am running the scripts if they are undefined and which my else statements are really pointless, so I should erase my else statements and put the code in the actual if.

Comment: Oh silly silly me! LOL I feel embarrassed well thank you. Could you explain to me what it all means though? I'm teaching myself most of the codes I write, so yeah. I know what if else if are, what is `typeof` and the `!==` ?

Comment: @ftom2 what is that fiddle supposed to show? the p element has no href attr, so it *is* undefined hence `typeof href !=="undefined"` is false and `typeof href !==undefined` is true (the string "undefined" is not equal to undefined)

Comment: for `typeof` look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof, for `!==` look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: I know what they do. If you had read the docs you just linked to you would know it *does* return a string!

Comment: @DavidMcMullin - LOL, the last comment was meant to answer OP comment not for you...

Comment: @DavidMcMullin believe he was linking those for me ;)